# Thevenin \$V_{th}\$ calculation problem

Tags: thevenin, linear, superposition

I'm back with my basic questions.

I'm trying to answer some questions, using Thevenin, for this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx5sPI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I must answer:

- \$R_{th}\$
- \$V_{th}\$
- Find short circuit current on A-B

For \$R_{th}\$ it is quite simple ( I hope...), and can be done calculating the total resistance of the following :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOb3we.png)</sup>

Which results in 0,75 ohm.

Now my problems comes. To calculate \$V_{th}\$, I started using superposition calculating the voltages for \$A_1\$ and \$E_1\$.

For A1 I calculate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlF7m.png)</sup>

Considering that the current in A-B is the \$A_1\$ current source, the voltage is:
$$V_{ab}'=A_1\times R_{th}=2A\times 0.75\,\Omega = 1.5V$$

To calculate voltage using \$E_1\$ source. My problem is that the point \$A\$, from the \$E_1\$ point of view  i in between of a \$\Delta\$ resistors connection (\$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$).

I tried to do \$\Delta\$ to \$Y\$ like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwuy8t.png)</sup>

Which is most probably wrong, 'cause it means that voltage on A-B is the same as \$E_1\$, that gives
$$V_{ab}=-E_1+V_{ab}'=-16V+1,5V= 14,5V$$

That is wrong, 'cause I know the result is \$-12.5V\$

I did something from or need I a different approach?

Comment: The circuit have used to calculate \$R_{th}\$ is wrong..

Comment: @nidhin Well,... good. Any hint? Because of the result is correct.....

Comment: @nidhin I corrected the first circuit, that was the wrong one

Comment: @nidhin Yes, sorry. Edited

Comment: are you sure of your answer because a simulation from proteus yields +10V as the thevinins voltage. try obtaining the nortons short circuit current first, and then multiply it with the thevinins resistance to obtain the thevinins voltage.

Comment: @user41704 I'm sure because of with nidhin's answer all my results match the values gave on the book where I found the proposed circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Delta-Wye transformation is wrong.
The two \$400\, m\Omega\$ resistors in your last schematics are connected in parallel. This can happen only if the current source is replaced with a short circuit. Which is wrong.

See the schematic below. (a) is the delta version and (b) is the Wye.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fco9Gp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok, so point A is floating with \$Y\$ connection. I thought that but sounded wrong to me.

Comment: @LPs A will be floating. And hence voltage at node A will be same as that at node A1.

Comment: Good. Thank you. I'll re-do my calculation

Comment: Well, all done and crystal now. Thank you very much.